# Printer settings into PostScript or PCL file

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, ghostscript, postscript

**I need:**
Print a large number of PDFs with duplex on specific output printer feeder

**I have:**
printing using ghostscript with 'mswinpr2' device

```
using (GhostscriptProcessor processor = new GhostscriptProcessor(new GhostscriptVersionInfo("gsdll32.dll")))
{
    List<string> switches = new List<string>();
    switches.Add("-dPrinted");
    switches.Add("-dBATCH");
    switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
    switches.Add("-dNumCopies=1");
    switches.Add("-dPDFFitPage");
    switches.Add("-dFIXEDMEDIA");
    switches.Add("-dNoCancel");
    switches.Add("-sFONTPATH = C:\\Windows\\Fonts");
    switches.Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2");
    switches.Add($"-sOutputFile=%printer%{settings.PrinterName}");
    switches.Add("D:\\11.pdf");
    processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), null);
}
```

**Problem:** 
one job in the print queue consisting of 2 pages takes more than 50mb, while I have more than 1500 PDFs with 1 000 000 pages

**What i think to do:**
Convert PDF to PCL or PS, edit these files and somehow pass the settings (duplex and specific feeder). Then send edited PCL or PS file as RAW data to printer

**Question:**
How can i pass the settings to PCL or PS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PDF files can't contain device-specific information, you clearly don't need to pick such information from the input, which makes life simpler.

Ghostscript's ps2write device is capable of inserting document wide or page specific PostScript into its output. So you can 'pass the settings' using that.

For PCL you (probably) need to write some device-specific PJL and insert that into the PCL output. However, PCL is nowhere near as uniform as PostScritp, it'll be up to you to find out what need too be prefixed to the file.

[EDIT]

You don't use -sPSDocOptions, PSDocOptions is a distiller param, so you need:

```
gswin64c.exe -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=D:\out.ps -c "<</PSDocOptions (<</Duplex true /NumCopies 10>> setpagedevice)>> setdistillerparams" -f D:\0.pdf
```

Notice that you don't need -f (as you have in your command line) **unless** you have first set -c. The -f switch is used as a terminator for the -c.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where i can find documentation on how to insert  PostScript into its output? On ghostscript.com i just found /PSDocOptions and /PSPageOptions but not how to use them.

Comment: They are distiller parameters (the documentation says so), so you put them in a dictionary and call setdistillerparams. You can probably use -sPSDocOptions and -sPSJobOptions on the command line too, but you'll need to use "" in order to cater for the spaces in the PostScript.

Comment: I am trying to send a PS file as RAW data with these parameters:
switch.Add (@ "- sPSDocOptions =" "<< / Duplex true / Tumble true >> setdistillerparams" "");
but it is still one-sided. Am I using the script correctly?

Comment: Switch.Add isn't anything to do with Ghostscript.I can't tell you why your printer doesn't enter duplex mode with that command, perhaps it uses non-standard code to do so.

Comment: Ken, thanks for responses. Now i testing converting PDF to PS via gswin64. I tried differently:
1) gswin64c.exe -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=D:\out.ps -sPSDocOptions="<</Duplex true /NumCopies 10>> setdistillerparams" -f D:\0.pdf    2)gswin64c.exe -q -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=ps2write -sOutputFile=D:\out.ps -c "<</Duplex true /NumCopies 10>> setpagedevice" -f D:\0.pdf

but when i open it with notepad i can't find string "/Duplex true" or "/NumCopies 10"
when i add them manually:
 %%BeginPageSetup
 << /NumCopies 10 >> setpagedevice
it works.
help!

Comment: No, you don't set -sPSDocOptions with setdistillerparams, the setdistillerparams **is** the switch. I've added it in an edit.